# Why my fresh angular-fire setup is broken in pnpm and working in npm when both package managers look at the same package.json file?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, pnpm

My following Angular-pnpm-angular_fire setup is broken.

With PNPM:

```bash
ng new pnpm-project --skip-install # create new project
cd pnpm-project
ng config cli.packageManager pnpm
ng generate environments
pnpm install
pnpm build # Working.

# Now and @angular/fire
ng add @angular/fire
ng build # Error
```

Error:

```
./node_modules/.pnpm/rxfire@6.0.3_firebase@9.17.1+rxjs@7.8.0/node_modules/rxfire/firestore/index.esm.js:137:40-53
Error: export '__spreadArray' (imported as '__spreadArray') was not found in 'tslib' (possible exports: __assign, __asyncDelegator, __asyncGenerator, __asyncValues, __await, __awaiter, __classPrivateFieldGet, __classPrivateFieldSet, __createBinding, __decorate, __exportStar, __extends, __generator, __importDefault, __importStar, __makeTemplateObject, __metadata, __param, __read, __rest, __spread, __spreadArrays, __values)
```

[image]

Now the same thing with NPM - working.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
ng build
```

When both package managers look at the same package.json, why them produce results those are very much different? (I understand pnpm does some efficiency things. But I think that should not let it incorrectly resolve dependencies)

Comment: Could it be that symlinks are not resolved properly when building the bundle? Because pnpm uses symlinks and stores it somewhere in the local system (`pnpm store path`) so that the package can be used elsewhere without downloading it twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the dependency requirements:

```
Angular 15
- tslib ^2.3.0
- @angular/fire 7.5.0
  - tslib ^2.0.0
  - rxfire ^6.0.0
    - tslib ^1.9.0 || ~2.1.0
```

Assuming there could me a dependency error, I done [overriding](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) the txfire>tslib version explicitly on package.json file

`package.json`

```json
"pnpm": {
  "overrides":{
    "rxfire>tslib": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

This fixed the issue.

---

Bug report: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/6165

Answer (score 1):

Faces same issue in an Nx monorepo

Accepted solution didn't work until wrapped inside pnpm:

```
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "rxfire>tslib": "^2.3.1"
    }
  },
```

---

Update, in the end changed to a `.pnpmfile.cjs` per PNPM's [faq's](https://pnpm.io/faq)

```
module.exports = {
  hooks: {
    readPackage: (pkg) => {
      // importing __spreadArrays from tslib issue
      // See https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/issues/31
      if (pkg.name === 'rxfire' && pkg.dependencies && pkg.dependencies.tslib) {
        pkg.dependencies.tslib = '~2.1.0';
      }
      return pkg;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Note this might work. But as per [rxfire package.json](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/blob/main/package.json#L109) compatible version of tslib is `^1.9.0 || ~2.1.0`

Comment: Thanks for the warning, ^2.3.1 seems to work and taken from open [issue](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/rxfire/issues/31)